# Preventing Clickjacking attack by Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, clickjacking

I want to prevent [clickjacking attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) in Vaadin 7 and 8 apps. As Vaadin applications are by default [designed to be embeddable](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-embedding.html), some configuration or code is needed to add safety.

Here's my first experiment, which adds [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) to each response to force browser to use same origin policy.

```
public class MyVaadinServlet extends VaadinServlet {

  @Override
  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // add clickjacking prevention
        response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");

        super.service(request, response);
  }

}
```

I'd like to know if there is better solutions for vaadin apps, existing vaadin configuration options that I don't know or if this implementation has drawbacks or limitations.

We do have Apache in front of our application, but I don't know if it would be brittle to add header manipulation there instead of having it inside app itself (where it can be tested and changed easily by developers).

Comment: We did decide to use header manipulation at Apache. Both approaches work.